# C# parse JSON API array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm trying to get the "Last" Object from this api in C#: https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=usdt-btc

I already have the script to get the array into my C# code but i don't know how to get this Object, i have googled around for help and i found things like these: https://www.codementor.io/andrewbuchan/how-to-parse-json-into-a-c-object-4ui1o0bx8 but it did not work for me.

EDIT
The working version is here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/5VFof9

```
//GET api array
    string GET(string url) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        } catch (WebException ex) {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // log errorText
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    decimal coin_price() {
        String array = GET("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=usdt-btc");
        decimal price = 0;

        //return price in price var
        return price;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        price.Text = ""; //Display price here
    }
```

Comment: maybe show us your code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LXnQ2UJS @Green thats how far i've came with it

Comment: @Green sorry first question didnt know that was possible

Comment: This how you learn(: and you even already got a nice answer

Comment: @Green do you maybe know whats wrong here? http://dotnetfiddle.net/UlxOfK

Comment: @FluffyMe420 Yes. Remove the 's' at the end of Result like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VFof9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSON.NET:

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VFof9)

```
public static void Main()
{       
    var url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=usdt-btc";
    // for a simple get, use WebClient
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

    // learn more on https://www.newtonsoft.com/json
    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    // root.Results.Last() is your last item
    // learn more on Last() at https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx
    Console.WriteLine(root.Result.Last().TimeStamp);
}

// generated with http://json2csharp.com/ (VS has a builtin with edit>past special)
public class Result
{
    public string MarketName { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double Last { get; set; }
    public double BaseVolume { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Bid { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }
    public int OpenBuyOrders { get; set; }
    public int OpenSellOrders { get; set; }
    public double PrevDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But im getting this error: https://gyazo.com/021baab143a28ddf5da7a2cbd05f6796 at this line

    double price = root.Results.Last();

Comment: @FluffyMe420 did you include `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Indeed, you where a few seconds faster. ;-)

As an extra:
if you want to use other naming for the properties than the Json fields, you can use attributes.



   [DataMember(Name = "last", Order = 1)]
   public double Last { get; set; }

Comment: @aloisdg i fixed it but now i want to put it in a label (price.Text = price;) But it tells me that it cant convert to a string

Comment: @aloisdg there is an error. also in your online version.

Comment: @BobLokerse maybe you know whats wrong here https://dotnetfiddle.net/UlxOfK

Comment: @FluffyMe420 remove the `s` at the end of Result

Comment: @aloisdg wich one? There are multiple lines with Results

Comment: @FluffyMe420 all of them. Also, I updated the example. (https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VFof9)